# Why am I getting left of '->head' must point to struct/union when it is pointing to another structure?

Tags: c, struct, queue

Trying to find out why I am getting this error, when head is pointing to a structure. It looks like head is pointing to the QNODE length. Why isn't it?

```
typedef struct Qnode QNODE;
struct Qnode
{
   int length;
   QNODE* next;
};
typedef struct lqueue lQUEUE;
struct lqueue
{
    QNODE *head;
    QNODE *tail;
};

 lQUEUE lqueue_init_default(void)
{
   lQUEUE* pQ = NULL;
   pQ = (lQUEUE*)malloc(sizeof(lQUEUE));
   pQ->head->length = NULL;
   pQ->tail->length = NULL;
   pQ->head->next = pQ->tail;
   return *pQ;
}
```

Comment: `lqueue_init_default()` should return a `lQUEUE*`, not an `lQUEUE`. Regardless of that, what is the value of `pQ->head` and `pQ->tail` after `malloc()`?

Comment: briduss, After `pQ = (lQUEUE*)malloc(sizeof(lQUEUE));`, what is the value of `pQ->head`?

Comment: ... and everytime you cast the result of `*alloc()` in C a kitty dies :(

Comment: The above code doesn't generate the error message you state.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile as-is that reproduces your problem.  Also include the **exact** error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

For this style of *queue*, `lQUEUE lqueue_init_default(void)` is returning a *structure*.

Unfortunately, OP's code is allocating memory for the structure and then returns a *copy* of the memory.  This loses the original pointer to the allocated.

Further, `pQ->head->length` de-references `pQ->head`, even though member `head` has not been assigned.  Certainly this is the reason for "left of '->head' must point to struct/union" as OP's run-time identified the invalid-ness of `pQ->head`.

---

How to fix depends of unstated coding goals.

Likely, to match `lQUEUE lqueue_init_default()` apparent intent, assign the members of a `lQUEUE` structure and the return a copy of it.

```
 lQUEUE lqueue_init_default(void) {
   lQUEUE lQ;
   lQ.head = malloc(sizeof *(lQ.head)); // allocate memory for a QNODE, not lQUEUE
   // If allocation successful ...
   if (lQ.head) {
     lQ.head->length = 0;
     lQ.head->next = NULL;
   }
   lQ.tail = lQ.head;  // start with head & tail pointing to the same `QNODE`.
   return lQ;
}
```

Another form of `lqueue_init_default()` may simply assign `head, tail` to `NULL`.  It depends on other coding goals not stated.

```
 lQUEUE lqueue_init_default(void) {
   lQUEUE lQ;
   lQ.head = NULL;
   lQ.tail = lQ.head;  // start with head & tail pointing to the same `QNODE`.
   return lQ;
}
```

Sample usage

```
lQUEUE myQ = lqueue_init_default(void);
```

---

I find this still of *queue* wasteful and not that useful.  A *queue* needs not a pointer to head and tail to add to both end in O(1) time.

Comment: `calloc()` would be cheaper.

Comment: @Swordfish Perhaps.  Either approach is O(1) time.  For me a `lqueue_init_default(void)` body should be only to set the one and only member of the _queue_ to `NULL`, yet that is another _queue_ paradigm.

Answer (score -2):

length is int. Pls do not use pointer value(NULL) and cannot expect pointer on length. What error is there is not in post.